# Moving my bicycle to another country

Tags: relocation, shipping

Suppose I'm moving from one country to another one, on a different continent. I'm taking a flight with a bunch of suitcases; I may or may not send some boxes using a parcel service or the state post of my country of origin; and I may or may not contract some shipping company for sending more stuff within a joint freight container.

Now, I'm thinking about taking my bike with me. What would be the best method for shipping that? By "best" I mostly mean cheap, quick and safe, in that order of significance.

I'm also open to ideas other than the means of transporting items which I listed above, of course.

Comment: Bike bag, pedals off, much as if you were going on a cycling trip at the other end?

Comment: @Gagravarr: I've never gone on a cycling trip before; at any rate, youre describing how to pack the bike, not how to ship it.

Comment: I'd suggest you start with http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=flying and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bicycles, then let us know what's special about your case as an expat that isn't covered by general bike travel queries!

Comment: @Gagravarr: I actually tried at travel, they downvoted me and told me to go here...

Comment: I agree with @Gagravarr +1 that bicycles SE is a good fit (and has quite a few relevant Q&A), as do online cycling mags such as  http://www.bicycling.com/culture/travel/how-to-save-on-bike-fees-when-you-fly

Comment: Partly disassembled in a [bike box with a picture of a TV printed on the side](https://medium.com/vanmoof/our-secrets-out-f21c1f03fdc8#.r20je82ce). Then check it in with the rest of your luggage.

Comment: Honestly, unless it's a > $3000 bike, the cheapest option in most cases would probably be sell it at buy a new one in your destination.

Comment: @einpoklum why did they tell you to come here? That would probably explain why your question is specific to expatriates.

Comment: @phoog: 3-year-old question, my friend.

Comment: Yet it is one of enduring interest.

Comment: @phoog: But I really don't remember why people suggested I delete my question 3 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final verdict: Sell the bike beforehand, even at a loss, rather than taking it with you. Too much hassle regardless of the cost. Like @DanubianSailor says, only for a super-expensive bike is worth considering anything else.

Answer (score 1):

While cycle touring it's common practice to pack your bike up in to a bike box and check it in as luggage on your flight. Most airlines don't charge anything extra for this service, but do check with your airline first.

Comment: To bring the expatriates angle into it, though, the mention of "hhh" in the question suggests that the baggage allowance is exhausted, in which case the cost of adding the bike box would probably be at least one or two hundred dollars, if it is even possible.